# issue while drag and drop list items in web app using dhtmlx 5.0 and wijmo grid

Tags: jquery, typescript, dhtmlx, wijmo

Webapp - using Dhtmlx 5.0, wijmo grid, typescript

My web app has a dialog box which contains a list of items. the sequence of these items can be adjusted with drag and drop. This works fine when we open the web app on windows PC but it doesn’t work when used with touch screen such as in Apple-IOS - safari and Android Chrome.
We are using “https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js” library for drag and drop options.

Please help…

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the drag and drop is not supported on toiuch devices in the dhtmlxSuite 5.
In this case I can suggest yo uto use the dhtmlxSuite 7, it supports drag'n'drop on touch devices.